# finite time nonlinear regulator problem

Tags: optimal-control

I have a question.
For finite-time nonlinear regulator problem, which means that we would like to design an optimal control or suboptimal control to drive the states of nonlinear dynamics to zeros at a finite time, however, we can not make the states to reach the zeros exactly at the finite time no matter how to adjust the weighted matrices. My question is what is the theoretical background of this phenomenon.
thanks
Jie

Comment: Can you say more about the system that you are considering, are you doing output or state feedback and is it deterministic or stochastic?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen  I am considering the state feedback and deterministic nonlinear system. Could you give me a hint about that?

Comment: not without knowing more about the system, is it controllable? Also, what have you tried? Have you tried [Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle)?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Actually, it is a well-defined dynamic system. Yes, I have tried. Everything is fine. Actually, I just can not give a reasonable explanation about why the final state can not reach zero exactly at the finite time.

Comment: How close to zero can you get and could that just be due to the limitation of numerical calculations? Is your input or your system in some way constrained such maybe it might be infeasible to reach zero in the proposed finite time (but it might be for a larger horizon)?